# How much weight can be supported by the air blown from a hair dryer?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, weight

How much weight can be supported/levitated by the air blown from a typical hairdryer? For example, when you place a piece of paper over it, it usually floats, but the same won't happen for a car.

Comment: Your question seems quite unclear. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: It depends on the circumstances: on the mass of the object and on its air drag (what is proportional also with its size). If it is a lead ball, then practically nothing. From a paper sheet it can quite big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice, this will depend on a lot of factors, but you can get a rough estimate by using an idealised case.

Let's say that we have a perfect hair dryer that produces a perfectly vertical stream of gas molecules with uniform velocity. Let's also say that all of the molecules perfectly rebound from an object above and return back 180$^\circ$.

We're going to ignore the real fluid dynamics of the air for now, because that makes things complicated.

We need to balance the weight of the object $mg$ with the rate of momentum transfer from the air molecules, which is $\delta p / \delta t$.

You can do this a couple of ways, bu the most instructive is to break it down as:

$\frac{\delta p}{\delta t} = 2\times \rho_{air} \times v_{air} \times f_{air}$.

$\rho_{air}$ is the air density, $v_{air}$ the velocity, and $f_{air}$ the flow rate (cubic metres per second). The 2 comes from the fact that the air makes a perfect rebound.

Rough numbers for each of these are:

$\rho_{air}: 1.225\,\mathrm{kg/m^3}$

$v_{air}: 10 \,\mathrm{m/s}$

$f_{air}: 0.015 \,\mathrm{m^3/s}$

That gives $mg \simeq 0.2\,\mathrm{N}$, or $m \simeq 20\,\mathrm{g}$.

All the assumptions we put in mean this is an overestimate, or an upper limit, but it gives a rough idea.

Comment: So to my understanding, (I have no history in physics, I'm just curious) this means that, at most, a hair dryer can hold up to 20 grams, right? Or do these symbols mean anything else?

Comment: @HappyPandaSkulls Yes, the estimate is 20 grams (g is the symbol for gram). However, maybe you have a more or less powerful hairdryer than the variables for velocity and flow correspond to.